# Performance of method

Tags: java

I am calling a certain method when i call it alone using a  it take an average (for 10000 call) of 11523 nano second but when i call it from a context of another class  it take about 95721

The method body is

```
public static byte [] validateRequest(KARPPacket karpPacket)
{

try {
    long before,time;
    before =System.nanoTime();


    byte [] encryptedTicket=karpPacket.getTicket();
    byte[] decryptedTicket=null;
    if(encryptedTicket==null)
        return null;
    if(encryptedTicket.length%16==0)
    {



        decryptedTicket = Encryptor.decrypt(encryptedTicket, ClientWindow.getSecretKey());
        time=System.nanoTime()-before;
        System.out.println(time);

         if(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString().equals(getSrcAddressFromTicket(decryptedTicket)))
         {
            ClientTicketManager.getArpCash().put(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString(), karpPacket.getSenderHardwareAddressFormatted());


            return decryptedTicket;
         }


       return decryptedTicket;


    }

    return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

why is that and how to improve its performance.
 I hope this enough code

here is the encryptor.decrypt method

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte [] encryptedByteArray,String keyString)throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
                                                            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
                                                            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    SecretKey key=loadKey(keyString);

byte[] clearByteArray;

Cipher dCipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES");
dCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key );
clearByteArray=dCipher.doFinal(encryptedByteArray);
return clearByteArray;
```

}

and the load key

```
public static SecretKey loadKey(String  keyString)  {


            byte[] encoded = keyString.getBytes();

            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
            return key;
        }
```

the other context at which a run the validate request method

```
package karp.client;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

import karp.client.presentation.ClientWindow;
import karp.client.util.Constants;
import karp.generalutil.common.Encryptor;
import karp.generalutil.destination.TicketDestination;
import karp.packet.KARPPacket;

public class KARPMessageHandlerP {

    String localIpAddress=null;
    ClientTicketManager clientTicketManager;
    KARPSender karpRequestSender=new KARPSender();  

byte [] srcMac;
NetworkInterface network;

    public KARPMessageHandlerP(KARPPacket karpPacket)
    {


        try
        {

            long before,time;


            localIpAddress=KARPReciever.localIpAddress;
            clientTicketManager=KARPReciever.clientTicketManager;

             srcMac = KARPReciever.srcMac;

//          



        if(karpPacket.getOperation()==KARPPacket.ARP_REPLY)
        {

            if(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString().equals(localIpAddress))//request sent by client
            {

                // if the reply was sent by the client no action must be taken.

            }
            else
            {

         if(karpPacket.getTargetProtocolAddressAsString().equals(localIpAddress))
         {
         byte [] ticket=karpPacket.getTicket();
         if(ticket==null)
         {   

         //delete the new entry from cash  and refresh the cash
          deleteEntry(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString());





         }
         else
         {


             if(validateReply(karpPacket) )
             {

                  }  
             else
             {


                 deleteEntry(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString());

                 //delete entry and refresh cash
             }

         }

            }
        }
        }

        else
            if(karpPacket.getOperation()==KARPPacket.ARP_REQUEST)
            {


                if(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString().equals(localIpAddress))//request sent by client
                    {
    //1             
                    if(karpPacket.getTicket()!=null)
                    {
                    //custom request no need to add;    


                    }
    //2         
                    else //new request need to add ticket 
                    {
                        String destinationId=(karpPacket.getTargetProtocolAddressAsString());
                        // if the map contain ticket to destination add the ticket directly
    //2-1               
                        KARPPacket customKarpPacket;
                        byte [] ticketDestinationByte=null;
                        if(ClientTicketManager.getDestinationTicketMap().containsKey(destinationId))
                        {
                             ticketDestinationByte=ClientTicketManager.getDestinationTicketMap().get(destinationId);
                                                    }
    //2-2                send ticket request
                        else
                        {   
                            ticketDestinationByte=clientTicketManager.getDestinationTicket(destinationId);



                        }
                        if(ticketDestinationByte!=null)
                        {

                        customKarpPacket= karpRequestSender.createKARPPacket(karpPacket.getDstAddress(), karpPacket.getSrcAddress(), 
                                                                            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress(), karpPacket.getTargetProtoAddr(),
                                                                            karpPacket.getTargetHardAddr(),
                                                                            ticketDestinationByte, KARPPacket.ARP_REQUEST);


                        karpRequestSender.sendKARPPacket(customKarpPacket);
                        }

                    }
                    }
                else
                {
                    if(karpPacket.getTargetProtocolAddressAsString().equals(localIpAddress))//check to see if the request is for the client
                    {

                    byte [] ticketRequest=validateRequest(karpPacket);
                    if(ticketRequest!=null)
                    {

                        //reply to the request;

                        String sessionKey=getSessionKeyFromTicket(ticketRequest);

                        TicketDestination ticketDestination=new TicketDestination();

                        ticketDestination.setDestinationId(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString());
                        ticketDestination.setSourceId(karpPacket.getTargetProtocolAddressAsString());
                        ticketDestination.setSourceDestinationKey(sessionKey);
                        byte [] ticketDestinationByte=ticketDestination.getAsByte();
                        byte [] encryptedTicketDestination=Encryptor.encrypt(ticketDestinationByte, sessionKey);


                        ///need to review target hardware address

                        KARPPacket karpPacketReply=karpRequestSender.createKARPPacket(karpPacket.getSrcAddress(), srcMac, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress(), karpPacket.getSenderProtoAddr(),karpPacket.getSrcAddress(), encryptedTicketDestination, KARPPacket.ARP_REPLY);

                        karpRequestSender.sendKARPPacket(karpPacketReply);

                    }   
                    else //delete ticket invalid request
                    {
                         deleteEntry(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString());

                    }


                }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(timeConsumed);
    }


    public static byte [] validateRequest(KARPPacket karpPacket)
    {
        try {
            long before,time;
            before =System.nanoTime();


            byte [] encryptedTicket=karpPacket.getTicket();
            byte[] decryptedTicket=null;
            if(encryptedTicket==null)
                return null;
            if(encryptedTicket.length%16==0)
            {



                decryptedTicket = Encryptor.decrypt(encryptedTicket, ClientWindow.getSecretKey());
                time=System.nanoTime()-before;
                System.out.println(time);

                 if(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString().equals(getSrcAddressFromTicket(decryptedTicket)))
                 {
                    ClientTicketManager.getArpCash().put(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString(), karpPacket.getSenderHardwareAddressFormatted());


                    return decryptedTicket;
                 }


               return decryptedTicket;


            }

            return null;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } 


    }


    public boolean validateReply(KARPPacket karpPacket) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {


//      KARPReciever.stop=true;
//      for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
//          {

        String sessionKey;
         byte[] encryptedTicket=karpPacket.getTicket();

            if(ClientTicketManager.getDestinationKeyMap().containsKey(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString()))
            {
        sessionKey=ClientTicketManager.getDestinationKeyMap().get(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString());
         byte[] decryptedTicket=Encryptor.decrypt(encryptedTicket, sessionKey);

         if(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString().equals(getSrcAddressFromTicket(decryptedTicket)))
         {
            ClientTicketManager.getArpCash().put(karpPacket.getSenderProtocolAddressAsString(), karpPacket.getSenderHardwareAddressFormatted());

//          after=System.nanoTime();
//           timeConsumed=(after-before);
//          System.out.print("kl"+timeConsumed);
            return true;
         }
            }
            //}


        return false;
    }

    public void deleteEntry(String entryIpAddress)
    {
        try
        {



        if(!ClientTicketManager.getAuthenticatedUser().contains(entryIpAddress))
        {
        if(ClientTicketManager.getArpCash().containsKey(entryIpAddress))
        {
        String updateCommand="arp -s "+entryIpAddress+" "+clientTicketManager.getArpCash().get(entryIpAddress);

        //printCash();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(updateCommand);   
        }
        else
        {   
         String deleteCommand ="arp -d "+entryIpAddress;
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec(deleteCommand); 
        }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }



    }

    public static String getSrcAddressFromTicket(byte [] ticket)
    {

        byte [] srcByte=new byte[4];
        System.arraycopy(ticket, 16, srcByte, 0, 4);


        String srcString=TicketDestination.getIpAddressAsString(srcByte);
        return srcString;
    }

    public String getSessionKeyFromTicket(byte [] ticket)
    {
        byte [] sessionKeyByte=new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(ticket, 0, sessionKeyByte,0, 16);
        return new String(sessionKeyByte);
    }

    public void printCash()
    {
        for(Object entry:ClientTicketManager.getArpCash().entrySet().toArray())
        {
            System.out.println(entry+" "+clientTicketManager.getArpCash().get(entry)+" entry in cash ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about *just* the `Encryptor.decrypt` method? If so, the rest of the code you've posted is irrelevant... you need to give us more information.

Comment: How fast is fast enough?

Comment: My eyes are bleeding.

Comment: Did you perform 10,000 calls against variant 2 (the one 'with context') as well?

Comment: no i am talking about the whole validate request , but yes i have found that the difference in time is due to Encryptor.decrypt. i will post it. see the update to the tail of the question.

Comment: @home , yes also 10000 run

Comment: @TonyEnnis , i need into run in an average of 11500

Comment: Why i am getting down vote, is there a problem in my question to get 3 down vote. i don't care of my rep and i can enhance my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you warm up the code it get faster, based on how it is used.

The first time you run it, it is very slow, it has to load classes and initialise them.

As you run the code repeatedly, it is not only warming up the code and triggering portions to compile it is also going to be warmer in cache e.g. a L1 access can be 100x faster than a main memory access.

If you run the code 10K or 20K times, all the code will be compiled and warm in cache with branch prediction working nicely.

Even then if you context switch and perform other operations you see a slow down again as your caches are not so warm.  You can see a slow down of as much as 2-5x.

BTW There are other factors such a resource bottlenecks, CPU powering themselves down to save power and running at lower frequencies.

Comment: Thank peter actually i am running the method alone 10000 to warm it up than i am running 10000 test to my context,so according to what you are saying that change to other context is slowing down my compiled code , so how i can evade that slowing down.

Comment: Its' quite likely you can't because you need your processor to do other things.  The only way to keep the code warm is to not let it do anything else. e.g. in low latency trading you pin the thread and have it busy wait. even then you see a small slow down due to timer interrupts.  However a 8-9x slow down is surprisingly high.  I suspect you are doing something different in your slower case.

Comment: i will post the other context, and sorry if it contain some programming mistake i am network researcher and not programmer

Comment: @BOB Are you controlling for the differences in the heap occupancy? You may be experiencing much more major GC-ing in the slower case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik no, it is the first time i hear heap Occupancy . do i have to increase/decrease it to have the needed performance.

Comment: Yes, heap size has influence, but more generally you should monitor GC occurrences either through the console output or, better, using the free `visualgc` tool.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I see that the hard part will only be done when `encryptedTicket.length%16==0`.   That's weird to me.  What are you really trying to say here? I doubt that a modulo of a power of 2 has any real performance impact, but if you're not careful you can enter the computational-intensive part of the code inconsistently for different test runs. Or you could get a non-real-world result leading to sadness when real-world data is used.

Also, when you do performance testing, be sure the `System.output()`'s are commented from any internal method.  Heisenburg is watching - the more you measure, the more you change the result.

If 95000 nSec is a common output and you want 11500ns on average, you have your work cut out for you.  The encryption routine is probably already pretty tight and you can't change it in any event.  So you have to change how often you call it or the load of other things in `validateRequest(...)`.  For example, if `ClientTicketManager.getArpCash().put(...)` is actually doing real I/O, you might get a lift by running several `validateRequest(...)` in their own threads.  Then when one thread is busy, another can service a new request.

Comment: thanks , i will remove the module and try optimize my code according to you instrucition

Comment: I don't think blindly removing the module is what's needed here.  What you need to understand is the nature of the performance.  Are you I/O bound?  Are you CPU bound?  If you're truly CPU (or I/O) bound, extra threads will not help.  You have to determine the nature of your particular problem.  Have you run a profiler to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: Profiler ?? i will search this word, i am a beginner programmer my code is used for network research