# VM Setting to use all my resources

Tags: java, jvm

I was asking a question about the performance of a certain method 
[Performance of method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134249/performance-of-method)
after some comments  i discovered that the virtual machine can take argument before running.
what is the best argument that make VM use all of my computer resources.

i have core i5 with 4 g ram

Comment: 4 GM of RAM isn't that much these days, even for a laptop.  If you need lots of memory I suggest you buy some more.  I would suggest at least 16 GB if not 32 GB. 16 GB costs ~$90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is using the `-XX:+AggressiveHeap` option; the JVM will then *attempt* to eat as much memory as it can.

Note though that this only concerns the heap; you may also want to size your permgen, stack size etc.

Note 2: that is for Oracle JVM; I bet OpenJDK has something like this too; as to other JVM implementations, no idea.

Comment: Then the problem is probably elsewhere... Note that this option won't make the JVM run any faster

Comment: have you take a look at my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134249/performance-of-method

Comment: Is there configuration for CPU

Comment: No there isn't. As to your previous post, isn't that fast enough already? 95 ms is less than the blink of an eye... For better performance you'd need to split the array and run in parallel threads.

Comment: oh sorry, it is very slow. actually i am a network researcher not programmer and i am working in adding authentication to ARP protocol and i want to say that my new ARP is almost like the normal ARP in performance since its used Symmetric encryption for 32 byte . but that code is not helping me.

Comment: ARP, you mean Address Resolution Protocol? How on earth do you manage getting ARP packets in Java???

Comment: Using jpnetcap, you call also use jpcap but you cannot forge custom arp

Comment: Are you sure this is not a problem of packets going round and back? Have you tried recoding the current authentication mechanism to see if it performed as it natively does?

Comment: I do see a problem with your current code though but one that will not be easily solvable: byte arrays are allocated by the cipher methods; it would probably perform _much_ better if you could get the cipher process to use pre-allocated `ByteBuffer`s.

Comment: no i have created a manual packet for testing and just running the methods,  i will die before  10k ARP request is done.

Comment: you mean to have the same byte array returned by the cipher method and this byte array refilled by that method??

Comment: Not always the same but a pool of it. In fact there are many ways to improve, but the first thing to do is have the cipher algorithms!